Why my character doesn't move, even though it's position is being updated?
I have this script for horizontal movement on my CharacterBody2D node:
extends CharacterBody2D

@export var speed = 400

func get_input():
    var input_direction = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    print('Input direction %d' % input_direction)
    
    velocity.x = input_direction * speed
    velocity.y = 0

func _physics_process(delta):
    get_input()
    move_and_slide()
    
    print('Current X  = %d\n' % position.x)

Looking at the logs, the script seems to be working, because position.x is being updated:
Input direction 1
Current X  = 479

Input direction 1
Current X  = 486

Input direction 1
Current X  = 493

Input direction 1
Current X  = 499

Input direction 1
Current X  = 506

Input direction 1
Current X  = 513

However, when I run the scene, the character doesn't move, it stays still at the middle of the screen. How do I fix this? I took a look at the 2d movement overview, but couldn't find any clues.
My scene only has a CharacterBody2D node, with the following nodes as children:

CollisionShape2D
Sprite2D
AnimationPlayer
Camera2D


The character was moving. I just had the impression it wasn't because the camera was attached to it. I didn't have other objects in the environment so I couldn't visualize the movement.
